# How to display the image inside the android widget background?

Tags: android, xml, android-appwidget

I have a widget layout xml which sets the src to the delivered android widget 4x1 frame image.Here is the widget layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:id="@+id/tuwidget" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/tuwidget_img_btn" 
 android:src="@drawable/widgetinitial" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

@drawable/widgetinitial holds the widgetinitial.png image example 4x1 at developer.android.com (AppWidget design guidelines).(4x1_Widget_Frame_Portrait.psd) What I am trying to do is display an image inside the delivered frame instead what happens is the frame image goes away and only the image I am trying to display shows up. How can I display the image inside the bounding box or the background?
Any help is much appreciated.

Another question - I think I saw in a couple of forums AbsoluteLayout is a deprecated feature for Android 2.1 and above. Is that correct? and does using AbsoluteLayout throws any force close or other exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AbsoluteLayout is deprecated.  It doesn't throw any exceptions, but its generally a bad idea to use it because it is really hard to design a layout that will work on all screen sizes.  There is generally a better way to do it using a different layout.

In your case, I don't follow exactly, but it sounds like you want to layer two widgets on top of each other?  An image with a frame?  To do so, I'd use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).  This is designed for having multiple layers of images.

[Common layout objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) is also a good guide to the basic layout types.

Comment: FrameLayout and ImageView together worked great...Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the end of the page 2 of this [pdf](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for helping Neuquino. I read the whole pdf. Very Informative. Thanks.